# How long will life exist on earth, and what life forms are likely to be the last?

Tags: science-based, biology, earth, habitability, far-future

Scientists predict that in around 5 billion years, the sun's hydrogen will be exhausted, and the beginning of helium burning will result in the expansion of the sun to the point where the Earth will be destroyed.

However, up to the point where the sun engulfs the earth, the sun is predicted to increase in luminosity at a fairly steady rate, resulting in an increase in the global average temperature on Earth.

So, the question: At what point is the last life on Earth likely to become extinct, and what are the last life forms on Earth likely to be?  Will they be single celled organisms, or multicellular?  Are there any particular adaptations that they would have evolved to survive earth's higher temperatures?

Please assume that there are no sapient, tool using beings surviving on Earth by this point, and that if any have survived to this point, they've long since departed for cooler climes and aren't interfering with Earth.

Edit:

Considering the environmental extremes that may be expected to exist as the sun's luminosity increases and the organisms that currently exist that can in some way tolerate some aspect of those conditions will be acceptable if it can be shown that the necessary adaptations are not of necessity mutually exclusive.

Comment: Rumors has it that in a billion years the goldilock zone will be way past Earth's orbit then our atmosphere and ocean will boil away while waiting for the red giant to form... in another 5 billion years give and take ;D

Comment: Isn't this just opinion?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a generic scientific question. The tl;dr is that carbon dioxide will start to run out and C4, followed by C3 plants will be the last things to survive other than possibly archaea.

Comment: I believe in as little as 600M years the sun will be so bright that the oceans will evaporate leaving a salt-encrusted earth in which all lifeforms but the hardiest salt and heat tolerant bacteria will perish.

Comment: I've said it in the past on our meta, but I don't think this question is at all opinion based. In our own FAQ this means "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or specific expertise." In what sense are the answers below opinions? They use 'facts, references or specific expertise.'. You could also argue all answers are fairly consistent. I've said it in the past, but 'opinion based' closing is detrimental, if indeed this question qualifies.

Answer (score 15):

### Life would exist right up to the end, in a sheltered place far from the surface.

Although the surface of the Earth may have been stripped of its oceans, saturated with radiation from the sun, and now a windswept inhospitable desert, life is resilient, and our planet quite saturated with it.

At this moment there is evidence that life exists 4.8km below the surface of the Earth. Really - life has penetrated all around the planet, to this extraordinary depth (not just in ocean, but within the planet). These lifeforms are mainly extremophile bacteria, living in extreme pressures and heat so far below the surface.

When these perish, then we get to perhaps the last Extremophile bacterium. Perhaps it would be a [Deinococcus radiodurans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deinococcus_radiodurans) - rumoured to be the most resilient extremophile yet that even has high resistance to radiation. This may now well be the last 'animal' to exist on the Earth, living deep down when it dies nestled between rock.

However, keep in mind that there would be many 'remnants' of life forms here, and also how our definition of 'life' is changing almost everyday. For instance viruses have recently been to have metabolisms, reopening the debate about their status as lifeforms, in which case these may still exist right till when the planet is consumed.

Comment: agreed, life far below the surface of the earth is nearly impossible to get rid off, it will be there until either the core freezes or something strips the crust of the planet off. its actually very hard to do anything to the planet that these organisms would even notice, much less die from.

Comment: @John -- I suspect that when the core actually does freeze (if it ever does), this will eventually lower the temperatures of the deep crust and upper mantle sufficiently that those little buggers will just keep drilling down deeper and deeper!  Couple billion years from now, planetary resources miners will come across bare rock Earth and, drilling down to the core for its irony goodness, will discover zillions of species of ferrophagic microbes eating the planet out from the inside.

Comment: @elemtilas life still requires liquid water, once the earth cools beyond the point that is possible even inside it life will go extinct. but you are right life will likely chase the water all the way down before that happens. Hmm, now I want to calculate if you could maintain liquid water at the core using pressure alone at a few degrees kelvin.

Comment: @John -- and there seems to be [water all the way down](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41561-020-0578-1), too. Down that deep, these buggers are eating what is essentially stone that contains water. Perhaps the [core will outlast the Sun itself](http://interestingengineering.com/how-much-longer-until-the-core-of-the-earth-runs-out-of-fuel)! And by the time the core & mantle do cool significantly, those buggers will just evolve to take their dinners ice cold.

Comment: Disagree--long before the Earth is destroyed it will be above the critical point of water, that will destroy any life based on our biochemistry.

Comment: @John Life as we know it still requires liquid water. It’s highly unlikely that we would notice something utilizing a different solvent (that is, notice it as a lifeform, not notice something we already acknowledge is a lifeform using a different solvent) in the type of extreme conditions we are talking about here simply due to how hard it is to collect samples in the first place.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Water can be trapped though. There is even water within Mercury. So probably water will always be a constituent part of our planets core well beyond no evidence of it is on the surface.

Comment: @flox Mercury has places cold enough for water.  Until the atmosphere is lost Earth's temperature won't have anything like that degree of variation.

Answer (score 9):

Evolution requires generations to pass before a change can be made and spread into the general population. The more complex the lifeform, the longer and more complex the lifecycle and the longer it will take to adapt. In a rapidly changing environment only simple life forms with rapid generations are likely to be able to adapt in the final years.

The last are likely to be a variant on the extremophile bacteria that already live around hydrothermal vents. Already attuned to high temperatures they don't need to evolve overly to be the last thing "standing".

Answer (score 2):

In many billion years, the planets may change their Orbits. There is no way of predicting if the earth will stay where it is, move away from sun, or move closer to the sun. Orbits behave rather chaotically if you watch over very long time periods.

Last swap was probably Uranus and Neptune, which is still visible in their orbits.

Scientists made simulations showing that Jupiter-like planets can migrate inwards or outwards and when they do this, their gravitational influence can push the smaller planets to orbits differing from their today's orbits.

Your question assumes that earth stays where it is, while the Sun changes its behaviour. You can instead expect that both change their behaviour. This then can fuel your story in a way that you can freely choose. Do you want a slow heat death, a quick heat death, perfect living conditions or a snowball death? Up to you.

Tardigrades are known to survive everything. They will be the last survivor in any scenario. At least, that's where I put my money.

Comment: We could create a pool. I won't have to pay off, because humans won't win. I'll take lawyers.

Comment: What will your surviving tardigrades eat?

Comment: Actually, tardigrades are nowhere near as durable as they are made out to be by many people. They’re still vulnerable to high temperatures (~150°C will kill most in a few minutes, and temperatures as low as 40°C will kill active tardigrades in about 48 hours), their eggs are known to be comparatively vulnerable to hard radiation early on (the consistently lethal dose for newly laid eggs is about 4/5 of the median lethal dose for adults), there are still some environmental toxins they are vulnerable to. Of course, they also need to eat somehow, as pointed out by arp...

Comment: They go into an inert state when there's nothing to eat. They continue later when there's something to eat again. Little wonders, those beasts.